# Passing command line arguments in Perl language

Tags: perl

I have trouble in assigning command-line arguments. I want to give the source path and destination path only at the command line.

For example

```
perl Test.pl /Desktop/Perl_Scripts/Task/ /Desktop/Perl_Scripts/New folder/
```

My code is below

```
my $source_dir = "/Desktop/Perl_Scripts/Task/";
my $target_dir = "/Desktop/Perl_Scripts/New folder/";

#my $pattern="$source_dir/$ARGV[0]";

sub copyFiles {

    my $source      = "$source_dir/$_[0]";
    my $destination = "$target_dir/$_[1]";
    my $DIR;

    opendir($DIR, $source);

    mkdir $destination;
    my @files = readdir($DIR);
    @files = glob my $pattern;

    foreach my $file (@files) {

        next if $file eq '.' or $file eq '..';

        if (-f "$source/$file") {
            copy("$source/$file", "$destination/$file");
        }
        if (-d "$source/$file") {

            copyFiles("$source/$file/", "$destination/$file/");
        }
    }

    closedir($DIR);

    return;
}

copyFiles($source_dir, $target_dir);
```

Comment: Try using File::Copy::Recursive
http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/File-Copy-Recursive-0.38/Recursive.pm

The command line arguments will be in @ARGV.
my ($src, $dest) = @ARGV;

Comment: if you execute perl Test.pl /Desktop/Perl_Scripts/Task/  /Desktop/Perl_Scripts/New folder/ it should create new folder and copy all files and sub directories in Task directory to new folder directory as same as Task directory . while trying to execute it ,script not giving any output as i expected if have any idea please help me .thank you in advance

Comment: don't forget to escape whitespace: `perl Test.pl "/Desktop/Perl_Scripts/Task/" "/Desktop/Perl_Scripts/New folder/"` or `perl Test.pl /Desktop/Perl_Scripts/Task/ /Desktop/Perl_Scripts/New\ folder/`

Comment: @Aprillon: You can *either* escape whitespace *or* enclose the parameters in quotes. You don't need both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
my ($source_dir, $target_dir) = @ARGV;
```

You can pass argument from command line like this:

```
perl Test.pl /Desktop/Perl_Scripts/Task/ /Desktop/Perl_Scripts/Newfolder/
```

If you have space in folder or dir name, just use double quote or escape the whitespace:

```
perl Test.pl "/Desktop/Perl_Scripts/Task/" "/Desktop/Perl_Scripts/New folder/"
```

Comment: is this correct way of : my $source = "$source_dir/$_[0]";
my $destination="$target_dir/$_[1]"; am getting use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at Test1.pl line error for both lines ..

Comment: @Sri - There must be a line number in error. You should tell us that line. The above method I told you is work for me and also a nicer way to receive command line argument. If you have any other problem you can post a new question.

Comment: After small modifications to my script  my ($source_dir, $target_dir) = @ARGV; is working for me thank all lot Mr.serenesat ..

Comment: @Sri : Glad it helped. You can select it as an answer, so this can be close as solved.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, the command line Arguments are Stored in `@ARGV`, where
`$ARGV[0]` contains the first Argument ( not like in C, where `argv[0]` is the
command).

For you:

```
my $source_dir = $ARGV[0];
my $target_dir = $ARGV[1];
```

For more sophisticated Options use [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) for actual
options.

Comment: thank you ..after including your lines am getting below errors .Use of uninitialized value in opendir at Test.pl line 
Use of uninitialized value in mkdir at Test.pl line .is this correct way or not .

Comment: I can't reproduce this error, sorry. On my system it is working properly, when I run `perl test.pl /home/dr /home/dr/new`

Answer (score 0):

My Perl command line arguments parsing routine is to use `Getopt::Long` for options (not your case) and this code for the rest:

```
my $source_dir = shift or die "You must supply the source directory";
my $dest_dir = shift or die "You must supply the destination directory";
```

I like the threatening voice of the formulation. Additionally, you won't have to check if the variables are both set.

Just to explain the code: `shift` without arguments performs shifting from `$@` or `@ARGV` (depending on the scope). If the shifted value is undefined, then the script dies.

Comment: after a series of compilation last one error is there that is You must supply the source directory at Test1.pl line that is at my $source_dir line ...do you have any idea ..

Comment: did you include the semicolons that I've forgot? :-)

Comment: If not, then the error is probably thrown because you did not supply the argument when you ran the code, e.g.  `perl Test.pl "source" "dest"`

Comment: C:\Users\sri\Desktop\Perl_Scripts\Task>perl Test1.pl "C:/Users/sri/Desk
top/Perl_Scripts/Task/templates/" "C:/Users/sri/Desktop/Perl_Scripts/Task/
Newfolder/" am using like this

Comment: If you have the line with the shift command inside some function, then it won't work. The shift takes `@ARGV` as its default argument only if it is in the global scope of the script. Try `shift @ARGV or die "..."`. Although in this case, I'd suggest to use another solution or to move the shift command to the beginning of the file to the global scope.